# Sqlite - SELECT DISTINCT using GROUP BY

Tags: sqlite, group-by, count

I have a SQLite table in which I would like to filter customers which have bought 2 or more DISTINCT items. The table looks like this:

---

```
customer  | product | quantity | date of purchase
---------------------------------------------
John      | coffee  |    1     |    02.20.2019
Bob       | coffee  |    2     |    01.13.2018
Chris     | milk    |    1     |    02.03.2012
Alice     | bread   |    1     |    05.01.2019
John      | banana  |    2     |    08.04.2015
Mary      | orange  |    3     |    12.16.2018
Mary      | orange  |    2     |    04.21.2019
Chris     | pie     |    1     |    07.02.2004
```

I've managed to select customers by grouping them using two rows in the GROUP BY query (customer and product):

```
SELECT * FROM test_table GROUP BY customer, product
```

This (almost) gave me all the customers that I'd originally wanted, except it also included *Mary*, which is not the desired output (she didn't buy two *different* products). I've tried to use a COUNT DISTINCT function to only show customers which have bought two or more different products like so:

```
SELECT customer, product, COUNT(DISTINCT(product)) AS counter FROM test_table
GROUP BY customer, product HAVING counter>1
```

The query successfully returned *Chris* and *John* without *Mary*, however it only outputs them once, showing only one of the products that they've bought. Is there a way in which I could get Chris and John with all *distinct* products that they've bought? The expected output of the query:

```
John      | coffee  |    1     |    02.20.2019
John      | banana  |    2     |    08.04.2015
Chris     | milk    |    1     |    02.03.2012
Chris     | pie     |    1     |    07.02.2004
```

Answer (score 2):

Using aggregation:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM test_table
WHERE customer IN (SELECT customer
                   FROM test_table
                   GROUP BY customer
                   HAVING MIN(product) <> MAX(product));
```

The `HAVING` clause above asserts that the "minimum" and "maximum" products are not the same, which implies that there be at least *two* distinct products associated with each matching customer.

For a more sophisticated solution, we could use analytic functions here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, MIN(product) OVER (PARTITION BY customer) AS min_product,
              MAX(product) OVER (PARTITION BY customer) AS max_product
    FROM test_table
)

SELECT customer, product, quantity, date_of_purchase
FROM cte
WHERE min_product <> max_product;
```

Comment: This does not produce the desired output. It returns each customer only once.

Comment: @Beartech Sorry, in my haste I didn't bother to check your exact expected output.  Please consider my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `EXISTS` to get all the rows:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM test_table t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM test_table WHERE customer = t.customer AND product <> t.product)
```

Result:

```
> customer | product | quantity | date_of_purchase
> :------- | :------ | -------: | :---------------
> John     | coffee  |        1 | 02.20.2019      
> Chris    | milk    |        1 | 02.03.2012      
> John     | banana  |        2 | 08.04.2015      
> Chris    | pie     |        1 | 07.02.2004
```

Or if you want 1 row for each `customer` with the products and dates as comma separated lists you can use `GROUP_CONCAT()`:

```
SELECT customer, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(product) products,
       GROUP_CONCAT(date_of_purchase) dates
FROM test_table
GROUP BY customer
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT product) > 1
```

Result:

```
> customer | products      | dates                
> :------- | :------------ | :--------------------
> Chris    | milk,pie      | 02.03.2012,07.02.2004
> John     | coffee,banana | 02.20.2019,08.04.2015
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=4e0bd30267dba27ae364ca07b31c6107).